# droping rows based on the values in cells by iterating through a list of values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of values and a dataframe. What I want to do is use a foreach loop going through the list and for each item in the list drop the corresponding row from the dataframe:

```
irrelevantList=['Blackcurrants', 'Cherries', '', 'Damsons', 'Gooseberries', 'Pears', 'Plums and Gages',]
```

fruitveg_df this one contains lots of colums and rows(there is a column with label '2004').

I tired this:

```
for item in irrelevantList:
    fruitveg_df.drop(fruitveg_df['2004']==item, inplace=True)
```

but it is not working. Can somebody help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you need:

```
fruitveg_df = fruitveg_df[~fruitveg_df['2004'].isin(irrelevantList)]
```

Comment: You are welcome :) Please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/345643) the answer as it will increase you reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call `df` your dataframe and say you want to remove items on column `fruit`

```
df = df[~df["fruit"].isin(irrelevantList)]
```